# Node.js Gulp no outputfile created

Tags: node.js, file, gulp

I have a Gulp script to concatenate, and minimize javascript.
It seems to be working but doesn't output the combined file.

The script is (complete - including extra debug bits):

```
// include plug-ins
var fs = require('fs');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var count = require('gulp-count');
var debug = require('gulp-debug');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var del = require('del');


var config = {
    src: 'dist/libraries/',
    dest: 'dist/js/',
    outputfile: 'libraries.min.js'
}

gulp.task('read', (done) =>  {
    fs.readdir(config.src, (err, items) => {
        console.log(items);
    });
    done();
});

//delete the output file(s)
gulp.task('clean', gulp.series('read'), (done) => {
    //del is an async function and not a gulp plugin (just standard nodejs)
    //It returns a promise, so make sure you return that from this task function
    //  so gulp knows when the delete is complete
    return del([config.dest + config.outputfile]);
});

// Combine and minify all files from the app folder
// This tasks depends on the clean task which means gulp will ensure that the 
// Clean task is completed before running the scripts task.
gulp.task('scripts', gulp.series('clean'), (done) => {

    //Include all js files but exclude any min.js files
    var files = [config.src + '*.js', '!' + config.src + '*.min.js'];

    return gulp.src(files)
       .pipe(debug())
       .pipe(count('## files selected'))
       .pipe(uglify())
       .pipe(concat(config.outputfile))
       .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dest));
});

//Set a default tasks
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('scripts'), (done) => { 

});
```

Which produces the output - including file list for verification there are src files:

```
[07:46:25] Using gulpfile <path>\gulpfile.js
[07:46:25] Starting 'default'...
[07:46:25] Starting 'scripts'...
[07:46:25] Starting 'clean'...
[07:46:25] Starting 'read'...
[07:46:25] Finished 'read' after 996 μs
[07:46:25] Finished 'clean' after 2.73 ms
[07:46:25] Finished 'scripts' after 4.26 ms
[07:46:25] Finished 'default' after 6.9 ms
[ 'bootstrap-datetimepicker.js',
  'bootstrap.min.js',
  'chart.min.js',
  'cycle.js',
  'farbtastic.js',
  'jquery-3.2.1.min.js',
  'jquery-sortable-min.js',
  'moment.min.js',
  'ol.min.js',
  'pablo.min.js',
  'popper.min.js',
  'proj4.js',
  'promisedIndexDB.js',
  'qunit-2.6.1.js',
  'toastr.js' ]
```

If I create an empty file, at `dist/js/libraries.min.js` it isn't deleted as part of the gulp tasks, however if i move the call to del() outside the gulp tasks it is deleted, so that leads me to assume that its not as simple as a permissions issue, or path issues.

Any idea what I've done wrong?

PS: its on a windows box, running in an admin cmd window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were using the wrong signature for the task.  The correct one is :

> task([taskName], taskFunction)

see [task signature](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/task#signature)

But your tasks look like this:

```
gulp.task('scripts', gulp.series('clean'), (done) => {   // 3 parameters
```

Merely changing that to:

```
gulp.task('scripts', gulp.series('clean', (done) => {
  ...
}));
```

makes it work - I tested it. So now that task has only two parameters: a task name and a function.  Yours had a task name plus two functions.

You would also need to change your `default` and `clean` tasks to this proper signature.  Also you should call `done()` at the end of the task as you did with your `cb()`.

Your new code uses task functions, which are better than named tasks for a number of reasons - but now you know what was wrong with your original code.  The main body of your `scripts` task was never being run.

Comment: Thanks @mark, Marked yours as correct as although its not what I ended up using it does answer the question "What am I doing wrong"

Answer (score 0):

I never worked out what was wrong, but went direct to the doc's and started again (previous version was from a example)..

Works with the below (much simpler) script.

```
// // include plug-ins
var gulp = require('gulp');
var count = require('gulp-count');
var debug = require('gulp-debug');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var del = require('del');

var config = {
    src: 'jspa-scada/dist/libraries/',
    dest: 'jspa-scada/dist/js/',
    outputfile: 'libraries.min.js'
}

function defaultTask(cb) {

    del([config.dest + config.outputfile]);


    // Include all js files but exclude any min.js files
    var globs = [
        config.src + '*.js',
        '!' + config.src + '*.min.js'
    ];

    return gulp.src(globs)
       .pipe(debug())
       .pipe(count('## files selected'))
       .pipe(uglify())
       .pipe(concat(config.outputfile))
       .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dest));

    cb();
}

exports.default = defaultTask
```